# php multidemensional array to simple array

Tags: php

I need this multidimensional array converted to a simple array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_zub] => 1
            [name] => Backen
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_zub] => 2
            [name] => Kochen
        )
)
```

A simple array:

```
array(
     [id_zub] => 1
     [name] => Backen
     [id_zub] => 2
     [name] => Kochen
)
```

function array_flattern($array){

```
    foreach($array as $key=> $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->array_flattern($value);
        }
        else{
            $this->result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

The function gives me this result:

```
Array
(
    [id_zub] => 2
    [name] => Kochen
)
```

Comment: because PHP overwrites the value for duplicate keys, you can't create an array with similar keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function works as intended, Your getting a "key clash" and the latter key's value is the one used. You would have yo have a suffix on the key if you wanted it in one dimension

eg

```
 Array ( [id_zub_2] =>  Kochen )
```